# how to solve the issue "hibernate not-null property references a null or transient value"

Tags: java, hibernate

while writing my test case for the table `Order` i have to set the value for the foreign key reference table `address`.i have set the all value and i want to get the `address_id`. it is the primary key for the table `address`.

table name : `order`
    primary key : `order_id`
    foreign key : `address_id`
    while writing test case for order in data access i have to get address_id by

```
  try {
        addressDAOImpl.addAddress(addressDO);
    } catch (CrafartDataException cdExp) {
        cdExp.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail();
    }
```

but it still get `address_id` as null. how to resolve it?

Comment: The error simply means. Your foreign key address_id is null which should not be. Check the data

Comment: check the data means whether in my database or hibernate

Comment: In your database. Also post your entity classs